# The Function listoff is calling always but it should be called only after the timer is expired  

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

> The date value is $date = date("D, d M Y H:i:s",1329907734);

```
$('#expire').countdown({
    until: new Date("<?php echo $date; ?>"),
    format: 'dHMS',
    layout:'{hnn}:'+'{mnn}:'+'{snn}',
    onExpiry: liftOff() ,
    expiryText:"Expired"
});
```

> The funcion listoff is always calling but it should called only after the timer gets expired

```
function liftOff()
{
    alert('calling'); 
    var reservation_id = $("#reservation_id").val();
    window.location = "<?php echo site_url('trips/expire').'/'; ?>"+reservation_id;
}
```

Comment: what value does $date contain?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the onExpiry property is expecting a function to run as a callback, you need to omit the parentheses so that you're passing a reference to the liftOff function rather than running the liftOff function:

```
$('#expire').countdown({
    until: new Date("<?php echo $date; ?>"),
    format: 'dHMS',
    layout:'{hnn}:'+'{mnn}:'+'{snn}',
    onExpiry: liftOff,
    expiryText:"Expired"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new Date object for the 'until' init parameter, but setting it's time to "right now".   As such liftOff will be called immediately.

Edit: you changed the question's content since I originally answered, it used to be:

```
until: new Date("")
```

I bet it's the same issue.  Please post the generated HTML source instead of the PHP code, my guess is $date is empty.